# What causes certain spots to be blacked out on my texture?

Tags: textures

So my model's hair (and other spots) are either blacked out or really dark, but only in spots.

[image: picture of model]

(**NOT THE WHOLE TEXTURE**)

This is probably a stupid question with an easy answer, but it's bending my small mind.
Here's the original texture to show you nothing's wrong with it.

[image: hair texture]

Comment: Do you see a similar effect if you use an unrelated texture? If so, this could be part of the mesh or another texture used by the material. If you can walk us through the steps to create a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example of the problem, we can reproduce it and test potential fixes to be sure they'll work for you.

Comment: You should tag your question with the engine / platform you're doing this on. Might elicit more useful answers.

Comment: There is most likely an overlapping UV in the models shadow map.